# css: Removing "shadows" from covered borders

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, border

I'm trying to show a part of a semicircle with CSS and HTML but there is always a little "shadow" that persists around the covered border. This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/willypuzzle/pen/ZmWOyY) that show what I'm saying. The red on the right shouldn't be shown. Maybe this is a bug of the browser. I tried it on Firefox and Chrome.
This is the sample code:

```
CSS:
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: black;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  z-index: 10;
}

HTML:
<div class="background">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need those two transforms. Try this:

```
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  /*   transform: rotate(-20deg); */
  z-index: 0;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  /*   transform: rotate(20deg); */
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I need the rotate because the dimension of the semicircle is crucial for what I would do.

Comment: You could adjust the dimensions of the circles but honestly you might want to look into using an [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) instead

Comment: yes, you're right but the behavior of the browser is however odd.